# After finding the average grades between the students, how do I append the average scores to the end of the list then convert it back to a string?

Tags: python

```
def parse_to_number(var):
    try:
        return int(var)
    except ValueError:
        return 0
inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'w')
inputFile.write("John Smith 80 90\n")
inputFile.write("Ryan Brown 80 60\n")
inputFile.write("Anna Myers 95 85\n")
inputFile.close()
inputFile = open("Students_1.txt" , 'r')
for line in inputFile:
    y = line.split()
    first_name = y[0]
    last_name = y[1]
    math_grade = parse_to_number(y[2])
    chem_grade = parse_to_number(y[3])
    ave = (math_grade + chem_grade)/2.0
    print(math_grade, chem_grade, ave)
```

I am trying to get the end result to look like a list but just adding the average to the end so it shows three different sets of numbers instead of two sets of numbers like this but save it to an output file titled "Students_2.txt" please help!!!

John Smith 80 90 85.0
Ryan Brown 80 60 70.0
Anna Myers 95 85 90.0

Answer (score 1):

You should use a context manager to open the file - notice you don't need to explicitly close it.

```
with open("Students_1.txt" , 'w') as input_file:
    input_file.write("John Smith 80 90\n")
    input_file.write("Ryan Brown 80 60\n")
    input_file.write("Anna Myers 95 85\n")
```

You can open the input file and output file in one line, like this

```
with open("Students_1.txt" , 'r') as input_file, open("Students_2.txt" , 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        y = line.split()
        first_name = y[0]
        last_name = y[1]
        math_grade = parse_to_number(y[2])
        chem_grade = parse_to_number(y[3])
        ave = (math_grade + chem_grade) / 2.0
        print(*y, ave, file=output_file)
```

It would be a good idea to store the paths in variables. Also break the code up into some functions.